# C not copying characters into new array

Tags: c, reverse

I wrote the following code to reverse a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
void reverse(char* str)
{
    int size = strlen(str)+1;
    printf("%d\n",size);
    char* rev = malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    int i,j;
    printf("Contents of rev as it is being filled: ");
    for(i=size, j=0 ; i>=0 ; i--, j++)
    {
        //printf("%c\n", str[i]);
        rev[j] = str[i];
        printf("%c", rev[j]);
    };
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s\n",str);
    printf("Result of trying to print rev after it has been made : %s\n",rev);
}

int main()
{
    reverse("Hello, World");

    return 0;
}
```

When the contents of the reversed string are printed, they are correct. However, when I try to print rev after the loop I get nothing. When is this happening?

Comment: `i=size` is out of bound in the array. Index goes from `0` to `size-1`. Also specify if it's c++ or c (not both).

Comment: @Jepessen See title.

Comment: `*sizeof(char)` is a bit redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the modified code which I tested as working

```
void reverse(char* str)
{
    int size = strlen(str); //read 1. remove +1 here
    printf("%d\n",size);
    char* rev = malloc(size*sizeof(char) + 1); //read 2. add +1 here
    int i,j;
    printf("Contents of rev as it is being filled: ");
    for(i=size-1, j=0 ; i>=0 ; i--, j++) //read 3. gives -1 here
    {
        //printf("%c\n", str[i]);
        rev[j] = str[i];
        printf("%c", rev[j]);
    };
    rev[j] = '\0'; //read 4. gives '\0' at the end
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s\n",str);
    printf("Result of trying to print rev after it has been made : %s\n",rev);
}
```

There are some things to note:

1. `strlen(str)` (without having +1) should be enough to declare the size of your string.
2. rev size, since you want to print it using `%s`, should be increased by 1, this is to add `'\0'` character, which is the indicator of termination of printing string. This is just how `printf` using `%s` works.
3. what you want is starting from `str[size-1]`; because str size is size, the offset should be one less than the size.
4. Only done for printing's sake. If you do not print, this (as well as 2.) is not needed. Edit: for completeness' sake, please read Jonathan Leffler's comment on this, I myself find it helpful.

Result in my PC:

[image]

Comment: I am glad to you find it useful. =)

Comment: The null terminator is required if the string is to be any use outside this function — the terminal null really isn't optional.  Further, the function either needs to become `char *reverse(char *str)` and end with `return rev;` or the allocated memory must be freed.  As it stands, the code leaks memory every time it is used.  Granted, the leak is in the original and hardly matters in the example `main()`, but memory leaks really matter in bigger programs, so it is good practice to avoid them in small programs too.

Answer (score 3):

`i = size` is out of bound array access. Change it to `i = size-2` to skip the `'\0'` character at the end of the string and you need to null terminate the reversed string.

```
for(i=size-2, j=0 ; i>=0 ; i--, j++)
{
      //printf("%c\n", str[i]);
      rev[j] = str[i];
      printf("%c", rev[j]);
}
rev[j] = '\0';
```

Comment: why size-2 , I think size-1 will do the job. size itself is strlen +1

Comment: Exactly , size is one more than `strlen(str)` strlen is the length of the string minus the null terminator so it should be size-1 isn't it?

Comment: `str[size-1]` is the null terminator. You don't want to copy that to the beginning of `rev`

Comment: @rohitshrivastava; No. `str[size-1]` have `'\0'`. You need to skip this.

Comment: @Kevin; No. `str[size-1]` is the null terminator. Indexing start from `0` in C.

Comment: @haccks So I added the extra space assuming I would need to insert the extra character on my own or that passing a string literal wouldn't include the null terminator, is this not the case?

Comment: @haccks I know, I meant `str[strlen(str)]`. `size` being `strlen(str)+1` confused me.

Comment: Sorry, this was a good answer but Ian's was more in depth. Thanks!

Comment: `i` used for indexing was initialized with `size` in the `for` loop and I was not looking at it . You caught it . ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are reversing the range `[0, size]` which includes the null terminator. So `rev[0]` is the null terminator, making it print nothing. You need to reverse the range `[0, size-1]` and then add the null terminator to the end. `size` in this case is `strlen(str)` rather than `strlen(str)+1`.

Comment: So this makes sense but doesn't work for some reason. I've updated my post to show how I've changed the loop.

Comment: Yes sorry I edited my post a minute ago. I missed that `size` in your code is `strlen(str)+1`. You can set `size` to `strlen(str)` and malloc `size+1` bytes and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

In your program you have copied the last `'\0'` as the first character of `rev`; as a result when you print `rev` it shows nothing. Besides, you have to add the null character '\0' at the end of `rev`. That is the solution of your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void reverse(char* str)
{
    int size = strlen(str);
    printf("%d\n",size);
    char* rev = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    int i,j;
    printf("Contents of rev as it is being filled: ");
    for(i=size-1, j=0 ; i>=0 ; i--, j++)
    {
        rev[j] = str[i];
        printf("%c", rev[j]);
    };
    rev[j] = '\0';
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s\n",str);
    printf("Result of trying to print rev after it has been made : %s\n",rev);
}
```

Comment: Posting code without explaining what you did is not a good answer. Also you aren't `malloc`ing enough space for `rev`.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.